# WordPress: Favicon not appearing on custom post types or child pages

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the following favicon setup in `header.php`:

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()." /assets/build/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png "; ?>">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()." /assets/build/favicon/favicon-32x32.png "; ?>">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()." /assets/build/favicon/favicon-16x16.png "; ?>">
  <link rel="manifest" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()." /assets/build/favicon/site.webmanifest "; ?>">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()." /assets/build/favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg "; ?>" color="#5bbad5">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

I have all the favicon files stored in `assets/build/favicon`.

On `/` or parent pages, my favicon appears. But on `custom post types` or child pages, my favicon doesn't show up.

The file paths are correct (otherwise they wouldn't show on the parent pages also).

Why doesn't it work on custom post type pages or child pages?

`index.php`

```html
get_header(); ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php get_footer();
```

`archive-knowledge.php`:

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>

<body class="knowledgeListing">
  <?php get_template_part('templates/parts/knowledge/level-one/listing'); ?>
  <?php get_footer(); ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you actually call the `header.php` file inside your custom post types and child pages templates? Sometimes it's easy to forget!

Comment: HI @Ruvee - I can confirm my custom post types are using `get_header()`. All of my pages use `get_header()` (via `index.php`), but it doesn't explain why on parent pages, the favicon shows, but not on child pages?

Comment: On the custom post type pages, you don't see any code from header.php displayed in source? Do you use a theme builder or something like that? Or a bought theme with customization options?

Comment: @Freddy I was just wondering if you're aware about the [site icon feature](https://wordpress.org/support/article/creating-a-favicon/#wordpress-version-4-3-or-later) in WordPress 4.3+? If so, why didn't you just use it? Or have you already tried it and the same issue happened? Can we see your `index.php` template? Are you using a single `index.php` file for all pages (single Pages, Posts, CPTs, categories, etc.)?

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ - Yes, I'm aware of the favicon option via the `customizer`. Uploading a site icon through here yielded the same results for me, the icon would only show on top level pages (not child pages) and didn't appear on `custom post types`. I've updated my question to showcase `index.php` and `archive-knowledge.php` which is one of my `custom post types`.

Comment: OK, but in your actual `header.php` file, do you have the unwanted whitespaces, e.g. in `"<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()." /assets`? (note the `" /`) Or were those just typos in the question? If yes, then have you tried checking the raw/server-generated source code of those child and CPT pages, and see if the favicon links are good (if they actually exist in the HTML `head`)? And if yes, then I'd try deactivating all plugins and see if the same issue persists.

Comment: like @SallyCJ said, check browser's console log.. Do you have any errors in icon paths? Which theme are you using; may have any theme options in it. Furthermore, are you using plugin in order to create CPTs?

Comment: You use two times favicon icon one will be from wordpress and second one you add in your header.php please remove it from your header file and upload using customizer

Comment: @ShakeelAhmad - I currently have the `favicon.ico` uploaded to the `customizer` only and it still yields the same results as the question. I have no errors on console and I'm using a custom theme.

Comment: have you remove the favicon from the header file?

Comment: @ShakeelAhmad - Yes, as per above, favicon is only present in the customiser now. The reason I added the favicon paths to header.php in the first place were because adding it to the customiser didn't show the favicon on all pages. But, both customiser and header.php approaches yield the same results.

Comment: Well normally this not happen, will need to check your theme

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why, but sometimes Chrome does not display the favicon, like other browsers. Try to add favicon.ico in your header file, like you did with the others:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

and place your favicon.ico file in the root directory. Thus, if the browsers does not recognize/get the favicon for some reason, they will take the default `favicon.ico` in your root folder. So that all browsers will find the icon eventually

Answer (score 0):

As I am checking the main issue with your href URL, you can use like this:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/apple-icon-57x57.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/apple-icon-60x60.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/apple-icon-72x72.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/apple-icon-76x76.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/apple-icon-114x114.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/apple-icon-120x120.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/apple-icon-144x144.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/apple-icon-152x152.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/apple-icon-180x180.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/android-icon-192x192.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/favicon-96x96.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/manifest.json">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/ms-icon-144x144.png">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

If you follow this type of structure, all browsers/devices will support it.

You can also generate an online favicon from:
https://www.favicon-generator.org/

Answer (score 0):

Your isue is closing php tags at wrong place, wp should not show them in any part of te site.

See this is the url in your head which is php tags closed in wrong place `"; ?>"`

```
<link rel="mask-icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()." /assets/build/favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg "; ?>" color="#5bbad5">
```

Correct url should be like this :

```
<link rel="mask-icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
```

I correctede other urls given in your question

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/site.webmanifest">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/build/favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```